# Which is the best framework for instrumentation testing in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

From my experience found that unit test have many limitations like initialisation of objects in the class to be tested. Is instrumentation test gain over unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have their merits, and you should be using both.

You should unit test as much as possible, and use instrumental tests to cover entire flows.

It really depends on how you structure your app, if you don't do it correctly, you'll run into issues trying to do unit testing.

Comment: is there coverage percentage for instrumentation test too?

Comment: @AbrahamGeorge I don't think tools could figure out coverage % of instrumental tests, no. But I would just do 1-2 per flow/user story, like logging in, creating a new account, or other common interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clearify both which you try to differentiate is Unit Test.
You can compare like `'Local/Small Unit Test vs Instrumented Unit Test.`
Local/Small Unit test is basically for Data Model where you  might have Android Framework dependency.Like for POJO classes.Local/Small Unit Test is very fast as it does not required any Physical device or Emulator to run.
Where as Instrumented Unit Testing needs physical device or emulator,hence it is slower than Local Unit test.
I would like to quote from Official Source

> Write small tests
>
> As you add and change your app's functionality, make sure that these features behave as intended by creating and running unit tests against them. Although it's possible to evaluate units on a device or emulator, it's usually quicker and easier to test the units in your development environment, adding stubbed or mocked methods as needed to interact with the Android system.
>
> Instrumented unit tests
>
> You can also run instrumented unit tests on a physical device or emulator, which doesn't involve any mocking or stubbing of the framework. Because this form of testing involves significantly slower execution times than local unit tests, however, it's best to rely on this method only when it's essential to evaluate your app's behavior against actual device hardware.

For more detail please go to[This](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals)